# How to show multiple bootstrap modals on multiple buttons

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple modals on the same page.

**For Example:** I have two buttons defined on the page like this:

Button for Modal 1:

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#firstModal"> First Modal </i>
```

Button for Modal 2:

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#secondModal"> Second Modal  </i>
```

**MODALS** on the bottom of the page, inside body, (don't work inside form tag either)

```
<!-- Modal defined first -->
<div class="modal fade" id="firstModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <form>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal-lg">Header</div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    body

                    <div class="modal-footer">footer</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal defined second -->
<div class="modal fade" id="secondModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <form>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal-lg">Header</div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    body

                    <div class="modal-footer">footer</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
</div>
```

> **Problem Statement:** The code given above works just fine, **BUT** it shows me only the modal defined first. Currently it shows me only #firstModal if I define #secondModal above the #firstModal than only #secondModal works.

Please enlight why the modal defined second, just darken the screen and doesn't show the modal. 
**Thank You**.

Comment: I just copied your code and it seems to work fine. can you reproduce problem [here](http://jsbin.com/cuqewebago/1/edit?html,output)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just Create a function on click: ( in angular)
<button ng-click="openOne()"></button>
<button ng-click="openTwo()"></button>
$scope.openOne= funtion(){
    $("#yourModal1Name").modal('show');

}
$scope.openTwo= funtion(){
    $("#yourModal2Name").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try it and let you know whether it works for me or not. Again Thanks for your response.

Comment: But yes, this is just a sample, i have not given any name for button between tag, please give names according to your requirement.